# How can I set a variable from a Nunjucks extension?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

How can I set a variable from a Nunjucks extension? For example, here is a template and an extension. The `x` variable should only be visible from within the `sample` block.

Template:

```
{% sample %}
{{ x }}
{% endsample %}
```

Extension:

```
function SampleExtension() {
  this.tags = ['sample'];

  this.parse = function(parser, nodes, lexer) {
    var tok = parser.nextToken();
    var args = parser.parseSignature(null, true);

    parser.advanceAfterBlockEnd(tok.value);

    var body = parser.parseUntilBlocks('endsample');

    parser.advanceAfterBlockEnd();

    return new nodes.CallExtension(this, 'run', args, [ body ]);
  };

  this.run = function(context, args, body) {
    // I'm guessing I need to mess with the context variable here?

    var ret = new nunjucks.runtime.SafeString(body());

    return ret;
  };
}
```

Comment: Assigning `context.x` before evaluating the `body()` might do the trick. To provide correct answer I would have to mess a lot with the debugger. Official nunjucks support answer to nearly anything is: " go see the unit tests https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/tree/master/tests, we're going to write some docs one day.."

Comment: what are you trying to actually *do* here? i.e. what are you trying to do with nunjucks templates that makes you think you need custom block parsing and a contextual variable?